# How to filter by file extension type list

Tags: python, boto3

I want to filter files using `filter()`. This filter should be base on file type `.png` and `.jpg`
I did

```
 client = boto3.resource('s3')
 bucket = client.Bucket(bucket name)
 objects = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=file_name)
```

Is there is any conditional query in filter search?

Comment: I've noticed that you have a number of questions with answers, yet not a single answer was ever accepted. If all of them were not good, then that's fine. But if they were helpful, acceptance is not only **a good practice**, but it also removes your question for unanswered list and reduces number of duplicate questions.

Answer (score 4):

> is there is any conditional query in filter search?

Sadly, there is not. You can **only filter by prefix**, not suffix. Thus, all the filtering you have to do on your side after you download all names. For example,

```
objects = bucket.objects.all()

for obj in objects:
  if obj.key.endswith('.png') or obj.key.endswith('.jpg'): 
     # do what you need to do on such objects
```

Answer (score 2):

Sadly the Admin hide my answer because it is considered as promoting your projects. I will make it minimal that answers exactly your question:

With [s3pathlib](https://s3pathlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), you can easily do:

```py
# import
>>> from s3pathlib import S3Path

# define an s3 folder, tailing / indicate that it is a folder
>>> p_dir = S3Path("bucket", "path-to-my-folder/")

# use the built in filter
>>> for path in p.iter_objects().filter_by_ext(".jpg", ".png"):
...     print(path)
```

The document for built in filter `filter_by_ext` can be found here https://s3pathlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/s3pathlib/core.html#s3pathlib.core.S3PathIterProxy.filter_by_ext

This will not be considered as promoting your projects, right?

Answer (score -1):

```
bucket = client.Bucket(AWS_BUCKET)
objs = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=your_prefix)

for obj in objs:
    if not obj.key.lower().endswith(('.jpg', '.png')):
        continue
    # your code
```

Answer (score -2):

```
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
log_files = [
    filename.key
    for filename in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='')
    if filename.key.endswith('.png') 
]
```